# Implement Scrollview based on screen size

Tags: android

I am building an android app that involves the use of scroll view and linear layout. I have implemented it and is working fine for all the screen sizes. But the thing is that if the screen size is big enough to accommodate the contents then the scroll view should not be be working. Instead the things should be displayed normally without the scrolling effect. Is there any way to achieve this effect?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorwhite">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:addStatesFromChildren="false"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relative2"
    android:background="@color/backgroundcolor">
            <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/intro_assets"
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="420dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
            <TextView
                android:text="Heading 1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:textColor="@color/colorblack"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font1"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

            <TextView
                android:text="As a person puts on new garments, giving up old ones, similarly, the soul accepts new material bodies, giving up the old and useless ones."
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font2" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Skip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView24"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font3"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: that's what scrollview does....

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It may be helpful if you'd include the code you're working with in your question. (Btw. signatures are [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed))